# Overcome login middleware in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i am  login from localhost use react to another localhost use express,

Hi Guys im using this code to post the login data via react:

```
 handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
  var params = Object.entries(this.state).map(([key, val]) => `${key}=${val}`).join('&')
  fetch("http://localhost:3006/login", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    body: params
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    //this.props.history.push("/landing");
    console.log("loggedin", responseJson);
  })
  }
```

and the other localhost the backend is :

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local",{successRedirect: "/landing",failureRedirect: "login"}) ,function(req, res){
console.log(req.body);
});
```

i need way to save my login data after i sent it so i can login to the page /landing.
normaly the code work when i remove the middleware.isLoggedIn from the landing page

```
router.get("/landing",middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
```

so is there is any expert in react can help me to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to save user data (user session) is "WebTokens". Yow can use [JsonWebToken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) to let the server recognize the user and know some data about him. This data is hashed and stored with the cookies in the browser. Any query from the browser (the client) to the server will be carrying this data and the server will read it and use any useful data.

For more info on how to use it with your express server take a deeper look at [this example](https://jonathanmh.com/express-passport-json-web-token-jwt-authentication-beginners/).

Comment: i understand what you try to do but i cant just start to build the website back end from 0 ,, i have make some test with the JosonWebToken its work when i sent post req with react, what i am trying to do is slowly put react to my website

Comment: Whether you are using react or any other front-end framework the cookies sent from the client are the same. Your issue is a back-end problem so you need to modify your server code to handle it without rebuilding the back-end from zero.

Comment: hmm Thanks for your advice